# django models translation doesn't work

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I try to use django translation but it doesn't work for me.

I created "locale" dir in my project folder and made .po and .mo files with "django-admin.py makemessages -l ru-UA" and "django-admin.py compilemessages".

USE_I18N and USE_L10N set in True
LANGUAGE_CODE set in "ru-UA"

in models.py I try something like that:

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from django.db import models


class Language(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255L)
    language = models.CharField(max_length=2L)
    image = models.CharField(max_length=255L)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'language'
        verbose_name = _('language')
        verbose_name_plural = _('languages')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

Answer (score 0):

There is one more step you didn't mentioned in your question, so there is a possibility you forget about it. You need to set the [LOCALE_PATHS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#locale-paths) setting.

Comment: When you log in to Django built-in admin app - is it in Russian or in English?

Comment: in Russian. Only model data in English.

Comment: What's the exact value of your `LOCALE_PATHS` setting?

Comment: I created translations for every applications in my project and everything works fine. If I create locale folder in project folder and set LOCALE_PATHS in settings.py django translations don't work.